# Seven people go to a restaurant which serves four foods, how many orders are possible?

Tags: combinatorics

Seven people go to a restaurant which serves four foods,
how many orders are possible?

---

The first person has $4$ choices, the same does hold for the others, by the multiplication law the total number of orders is given by $4^7$ but the answer is $\frac{10!}{7!3!}$ I don't understand why this is true, it looks like we are dealing with the number of nonnegative integral solutions to the equation $a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4=7$.

I don't see the connection.

Comment: Apparently there is some other clause that one food can not be ordered by more than one person.

Comment: @hola How would that work when there are 7 people and 4 possible foods?

Comment: @Arthur Some people would remain hungry.

Answer (score 1):

The restaurant kitchen doesn't care which person orders which dish. All they care about is how many there are of each dish. That's apparently what we are asked to count. So the answer can indeed be found by counting the number of nonnegative integral solutions to

> The number of people who want dish 1, plus the number of people who want dish 2, plus the number of people who want dish 3, plus the number of people who want dish 4 totals 7

Comment: @45465 It's not $(2^4)^7$, that's way too high. That would be the answer is each person could choose up to one of each dish, not just up to one dish. If they can choose either one of the dishes or nothing, that's basically just having five dishes to choose from, where one is empty, so we get $5^7$. I thought the entire premise in your question was to ask how $\binom{10}{7}$ could possibly be the answer. Clearly, as that's the given solution, there must be some way. The interpretation I present here is the most plausible one.

Comment: Yes, it's ambiguous. That's a very common peril with probability and combinatorics. Problem authors often rely on key words to implicitly carry their meaning about order and replacement to the readers. This can fail. I agree that this problem is ambiguous, but the given answer disambiguates it.

Comment: @45365 The meaning of this problem depends entirely on what the word "order" means to someone in a restaurant. Does it mean the order that the waiter takes from the customers, or the order that the waiter passes on to the kitchen? It is unclear. However, after looking at the given answer, clearly the latter interpretation was meant.